# A value randomly changes even though I haven't touched it.

Tags: function, cobol

```
perform 200-ctTerm.

    100-cTrans.
    *> open error file
     open output error-file
    *> change values of cus bal and prodprice for comp
     compute cCusBal = function numval(lst-cusBal) end-compute.
     compute cProdPrice = function numval(lst-prodPrice) end-compute.
     display "CUST BAL1: "cCusBal *> OUPUT: 05815 the corrected value

    *> start of transaction comp

     if lst-prodStock = 0 then
    *> 0 items in stock, update error-file
       set eProdNum to lst-prodNum
       set zStock to "out of prod"
       set eTransNum to lst-transCusNum
       set NBH to "could not be handled"
       write out-error end-write *> example of output to error-file - prodnum of out prod cusNum could not be handled

       close error-file *> close file
       go to 200-ctTerm

     end-if.

       *> order > stock
     if lst-transOrder is greater than lst-prodStock then
          compute tPrice = lst-prodStock * cProdPrice *> transaction only consists of # in stock
          if lst-prodStock is greater or equal lst-transOrder then
           compute tPrice = lst-transOrder * cProdPrice *> get orginal total price
           *> check order codes and then apply codes
           evaluate lst-transCode
               when "A"
                   compute discount = tPrice * .10
                   compute tPrice = tPrice - discount
                   compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-prodStock *>stock now at 0
               when "B"
                   compute discount = tPrice * .20
                   compute tPrice = tPrice - discount
                   compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-prodStock *>stock now at 0
               when "C"
                   compute discount = tPrice * .25
                   compute tPrice = tPrice - discount
                   compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-prodStock *>stock now at 0

               when "D"
                   if lst-transOrder greater or equal 3 then
                       compute tPrice = tPrice - cProdPrice *> if order > 3 get one free
                       compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-prodStock *>stock now at 0
                   end-if
               when "E" 
                   if lst-transOrder greater or equal 1 then
                       compute BOGO = lst-transOrder / 2  *> check to see how many free
                       compute tPrice = tPrice - cProdPrice * BOGO *> apply buy one get one
                       compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-prodStock *>stock now at 0
                   end-if
               when "Z"
                   compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-prodStock *>stock now at 0
               end-evaluate 
     end-if.

      *> stock >= order
       if lst-prodStock is greater or equal lst-transOrder then
           compute tPrice = lst-transOrder * cProdPrice *> get orginal total price
           *> check order codes and then apply codes
           evaluate lst-transCode
               when "A"
                   compute discount = tPrice * .10 *>get discount
                   compute tPrice = tPrice - discount *>update total price of transaction.
                   compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-transOrder *>update stock

               when "B"
                   compute discount = tPrice * .20 *>get discount
                   compute tPrice = tPrice - discount *>update total price of transaction.
                   compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-transOrder *>update stock
               when "C"
                   compute discount = tPrice * .25 *>get discount
                   compute tPrice = tPrice - discount *>update total price of transaction.
                   compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-transOrder *>update stock

               when "D"
                   if lst-transOrder greater or equal 3 then
                       compute tPrice = tPrice - cProdPrice *> if order > 3 get one free
                       compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-transOrder *>update stock
                   end-if
               when "E" 
                   if lst-transOrder greater or equal 1 then
                       compute BOGO = lst-transOrder / 2  *> check to see how many free
                       compute tPrice = tPrice - cProdPrice * BOGO *> apply buy one get one
                       compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-transOrder *>update stock
                   end-if
               when "Z"
                   compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-transOrder *>update stock
               end-evaluate 
      display "total Price: "tPrice
      display "CUS BAL2 "cCusBal *> OUTP: 05810 - randomly changed
      compute cCusBal = cCusBal + tPrice *> which cause this to be wrong
      display "New balace: "cCusBal 
      move cCusBal to lst-cusBal

     end-if.
     go to 200-ctTerm
    exit.
```

I compute cCusBal and get the correct answer (lst-cusBal = 058.15), then after I do my computational section where I don't touch cCusBal its value randomly changes from 05815 to 05810. This affects the compute sCusBal + tPrice and I'm off by 5 of the expected value.  I have no idea whats going on here and any help would be appreciated

Comment: i didnt have my  working-storage section.

Comment: Can you provide anything from your data division? Without it, I don't see how anybody can figure what's happening. Perhaps cCusBal has accidently been REDEFINE'd.

Comment: Also, is there any reason for using "compute lst-prodStock = lst-prodStock - lst-prodStock" instead of "move zero to lst-prodStock"?

Comment: Are you using "managed COBOL"? Your `SET` statements I don't think would work elsewhere, and goes with "no WORKING-STORAGE" as far as I understand it. The code you have shown does a `PERFORM` of a different paragraph than you've shown then, if the PERFORM is actually immediately before the paragraph you have shown, "drops through" into the paragraph, and then at the end there is a `GO TO` the paragraph which is PERFORMed. You need to sort all that out (even if it is "managed COBOL"), it is a terrible mess already, and can only get worse.